# Passing Props to React-Router 4.0.0 Children Routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to migrate an existing react-router 3.0.0 app to [4.0.0](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/v4). Within the router, I need pass an additional non routing-related `prop` to its children.

There are a few somewhat hacky ways to accomplish this in previous versions of react-router, [detailed in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31862839/1179207). My personal favorite was [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37215523/1179207) using `cloneElement`, since it ensured that all of the react-router props were copied over as well:

```
// react-router 3.0.0 index.js JSX
<Router history={browserHistory}
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="/user/:userId" component={User} />
    <IndexRoute component={Home} />
  </Route>
</Routes>

// App component JSX (uses cloneElement to add a prop)
<div className="App">
  { cloneElement(props.children, { appState: value }) }
</div>
```

So far my new App component looks like:

```
// react-router 4.0.0 App component JSX (moved routing code out of index.js and into here)
<BrowserRouter>
  <div className="App">
    <Match exactly pattern="/" component={Home} />
    <Match pattern="/user/:userId" component={User} />
    <Miss component={Home} />
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

What's the best way to add the `appState` prop to each of the `Match`'s components while retaining the provided router props?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`<Route>` can take a `render` prop instead of a `component`. This allows you to inline the component definition.

```
<Route path='/user/:userId' render={(props) => (
  <User appState={value} {...props} />
)} />
```