# In React Router v4 is it possible to subscribe for route changes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history

I am wondering what would be the best pattern to subscribe for browser history changes with the latest version of `react-router`. I was reading the current [documentation](https://react-router.now.sh/), but it looks like the only option which is mentioned there is by explicitly retrieving props passed by the `<Match/>` container to the `render` function or to the `component`. This solution is also described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41006114/2817257

But what if I would like to get route parameters deeper in the component tree in a clean way?

What I am thinking about is to create a container component that retrieves `router` from context and subscribes to location changes. However, with the current version  `4.0.0-alpha.6` even though the `router` object is already in the context, it only contains the following methods:

- blockTransitions
- createHref
- replaceWith
- transitionTo

which are not very promising, because it looks like `router` is not exposing the `history` object at all. Maybe there's some other object that's added to the context that could be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

`react-router` docs are down ATM, but in v3 you could pass [an `onUpdate` function](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#onupdate) as a prop to the `Router` component to listen to router state changes.

Other option is to import `browserHistory`, which is is implemented with [`history`](https://github.com/mjackson/history/) (again v3 knowledge as v4 docs are down) and subscribe to history changes with `listen`, like this

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'

browserHistory.listen((location, action) => {
  // do whatever you need here
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think that unfortunately `browserHistory` instance is no longer available at `react-router` v4.

Comment: You can import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory', assign the fn call to a variable, and set that to the history prop on the router. Then you'll have access to history wherever your history variable is exposed.

Comment: Also note that the history.pushState() and history.replaceState() calls don't trigger the popstate event, so this answer alone won't cover all route changes.