# How to pass componentWillMount EventEmitter prop to <Route> in React Router 4?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I am trying to pass a prop to my child component using the `render` [method](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func) in my `<Route>` in react-router 4. Saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41005697/passing-props-to-react-router-4-0-0-children-routes) which mentioned passing props in your `<Route>`s over `{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { key: value })}` used in react-router 3. How would I pass a prop defined in the `componentWillMount` lifecycle? Specifically, I want to use the `EventEmitter` object.

Here is the problematic `<Route>`s in Index.js:

```
<Route path="/screen3" render={ (props) => 
    <Screen3 eventEmitter={ this.eventEmitter } {...props} /> 
} />
```

Full Index.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Route, BrowserRouter, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';
import Screen3 from './screens/Screen3';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        screenIndex: 1
    }
  }  

  componentWillMount() {
    this.eventEmitter = new EventEmitter()
    this.eventEmitter.addListener("navigateScreen", ({screenIndex}) => {
        this.updateScreen({newScreenIndex: screenIndex})
    })
  }

  updateScreen({newScreenIndex}) {
    this.setState({ screenIndex: newScreenIndex })
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="app">
          <div className="main-content">
            {this.props.children}
          </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>       
    <App>
        <div>
            <Route path="/screen3" render={ (props) => 
                <Screen3 eventEmitter={ this.eventEmitter } {...props} /> 
            } /> 
        </div>
    </App>
  </BrowserRouter>, 
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

In my Screen3.js component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Screen3 extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.eventEmitter.emit("navigateScreen", {screenIndex: 3})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="screen screen3">
        <h1>SCREEN 3 DATA</h1>
      </div>
    )

  }
```

}

```
export default Screen3
```

The `eventEmitter` prop is undefined when I do a `console.log(this.props.eventEmitter)` in my Screen3 component. Any ideas?

Comment: Include your `index.js`. The `this.eventEmitter` doesn't seem to refer to anything in your route.

Comment: @norbertpy can you clarify what you mean by "Include your Index.js? I am able to access `this.eventEmitter` in the `render()` lifecyle in `Index.js`, just not sure how to use it in the `<Route>`

Comment: I think he means the `this.eventEmitter` in `ReactDOM.render` function. What's the `this` is referring to there?

Comment: If you move the `div` and the routes inside of it into the render function of `App` component then `this` will be correctly pointing to `App`.

Comment: thanks @SamRad. just added the full `Index.js`. Is putting all the `<Route>`s inside the `render()` function the right pattern vs. putting them in  `ReactDOM.render()`?

Comment: That's typical react. Either that or you can use more ceremonial stuff like 'render props' pattern. Just google it. Routes are just react components. Nothing special about them.

Comment: @SamRad gotcha thanks!